# Javascript onClick unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have following html code :

```
<input type="submit" name="" value="" class="searchbtn" onclick="search_button();">
```

I want to unbind this click event and bind my own click with a new function on document ready.
Can anyone have a solution of this?
I had already used unbind, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Unbinding inline javascript doesn't work, you have to remove the attribute

```
$('.searchbtn').removeAttr('onclick').on('click', function() {
    // stuff
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/C23Pa/2/)